# "error": "oauth failed" with HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, oauth, httpurlconnection, oauth-2.0

So I have implemented so far asking for the user to give me permission to their google account. I need to then take that token and add it to the following URL https://api.comma.ai/v1/auth/?access_token= to get a token from them and store that token so that I can use it. However, as the title I get {"success": false, "error": "oauth failed"} which is better than the 401 that I was getting...I think? This is my first time diving into this. I am not sure where I am going wrong on this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context mContext = MainActivity.this;
    private AccountManager mAccountManager;
    private AuthPreferences authPreferences;
    EditText emailText;
    TextView responseView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    static final String API_KEY = "";
    static final String API_URL = "https://api.comma.ai/v1/auth/?access_token=";
    static final String ClientId = "45471411055-m902j8c6jo4v6mndd2jiuqkanjsvcv6j.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    static final String ClientSecret = "";
    static final String SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
    private static final int AUTHORIZATION_CODE = 1993;
    private static final int ACCOUNT_CODE = 1601;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        responseView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseView);
        emailText =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailText);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        final Context context = this;
        mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
        authPreferences = new AuthPreferences(this);


        SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (authPreferences.getUser() != null && authPreferences.getToken() != null) {
                    doCoolAuthenticatedStuff();
                    new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();
                } else{
                    chooseAccount();
                }
            }
        });
//        Button queryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.queryButton);
//
//        queryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                if (isNetworkAvailable() == true) {
//                    new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();
//                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NavDrawerActivity.class);
//                    startActivity(intent);
//                } else {
//                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Network Service, please check your WiFi or Mobile Data Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                }
//            }
//        });

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean dontShowDialog = sharedPref.getBoolean("DONT_SHOW_DIALOG", false);
        if (!dontShowDialog) {
            WifivsDataDialog myDiag = new WifivsDataDialog();
            myDiag.show(getFragmentManager(), "WiFi");
            myDiag.setCancelable(false);
        }
    }

    private void doCoolAuthenticatedStuff() {
        Log.e("AuthApp", authPreferences.getToken());
    }

    private void chooseAccount() {
        Intent intent = AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[]{"com.google"}, false, null, null, null, null);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACCOUNT_CODE);
    }

    private void requestToken() {
        Account userAccount = null;
        String user = authPreferences.getUser();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        for (Account account : mAccountManager.getAccountsByType(GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE)) {
            if (account.name.equals(user)) {
                userAccount = account;
                break;
            }
        }

        mAccountManager.getAuthToken(userAccount, "oauth2:" + SCOPE, null, this, new OnTokenAcquired(), null);
    }

    private void invalidateToken()
    {
        AccountManager mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
        mAccountManager.invalidateAuthToken("com.google", authPreferences.getToken());
        authPreferences.setToken(null);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == AUTHORIZATION_CODE) {
                requestToken();
            } else if (requestCode == ACCOUNT_CODE) {
                String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                authPreferences.setUser(accountName);

                // invalidate old tokens which might be cached. we want a fresh
                // one, which is guaranteed to work
                invalidateToken();

                requestToken();
            }
        }
    }

    public class OnTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>
    {
        @Override
        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result)
        {
            try {
                Bundle bundle = result.getResult();
                Intent launch = (Intent) bundle.get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
                if(launch != null)
                {
                    startActivityForResult(launch, AUTHORIZATION_CODE);
                } else {
                    String token = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);

                    authPreferences.setToken(token);
                    doCoolAuthenticatedStuff();
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isNetworkAvailable()
    {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
        {
            Log.e("Network Testing", "Available");
            return true;
        }
        Log.e("Network Testing", "Not Available");
        return false;
    }



    class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private Exception exception;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            responseView.setText("");
        }

        protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {

            // Do some validation here

            try {
                URL url = new URL(API_URL + authPreferences);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.addRequestProperty("client_id", ClientId);
                urlConnection.addRequestProperty("client_secret", ClientSecret);
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth " + authPreferences);
                try {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    return stringBuilder.toString();
                }
                finally{
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            if(response == null) {
                response = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.i("INFO", response);
            responseView.setText(response);
            //
            // TODO: check this.exception
            // TODO: do something with the feed

//            try {
//                JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
//                String requestID = object.getString("requestId");
//                int likelihood = object.getInt("likelihood");
//                JSONArray photos = object.getJSONArray("photos");
//                .
//                .
//                .
//                .
//            } catch (JSONException e) {
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the AuthPreferences.java if anyone needs to look at it.

```
public class AuthPreferences {
    private static final String KEY_USER = "user";
    private static final String KEY_TOKEN = "token";

    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    public AuthPreferences(Context context) {
        preferences = context
                .getSharedPreferences("auth", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_USER, user);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void setToken(String password) {
        Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_TOKEN, password);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return preferences.getString(KEY_USER, null);
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return preferences.getString(KEY_TOKEN, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably remove secret keys from your code.

Comment: David, the secret key is on GitHub haha. So are you saying remove it when posting it or in general. If in general should I put it in my manifest file then? Furthermore, any idea on the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0):

I did never use Android for OAuth2 but as far as I understand your code I think there are a few errors.
Fix the RetrieveFeedTask (OAuth2 Token is typically Bearer Token for all I know), use the access token like this:

```
URL url = new URL(API_URL + authPreferences.getToken());
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.addRequestProperty("client_id", ClientId);
urlConnection.addRequestProperty("client_secret", ClientSecret);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth " + authPreferences.getToken());
```

Furthermore I am not sure if your approach is correct (can you post a link where this snippet is from?). As far as I understand OAuth2 I would expect that at this time you can simply authorize by using a Bearer token und do no longer have to supply the access token in the URL / the client id and secrets. Or you may be missing a step (e.g. splitting the upper codes in two requests). Make sure you are explicitely following the OAuth2 standard and be sure what grant type you are using. Then debug your application to find out where the error is returned.